# Alternative to new method to avoid duplicating code

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to apply the same operations to different streams (using Java 8 at the moment)

Background: I am trying to get dimension data out of a Tika **Metadata** object

The following works but repeats code (*metadata* is a Tika **Metadata** object):

```
    private static void processDimensions(final Metadata metadata) {
        Optional<Integer> optWidth = Arrays.stream(new String[] {"tiff:ImageWidth", "Image Width"})
                .map(metadata::get)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(v -> v.replace("pixels", ""))
                .map(Integer::parseInt).findFirst();
        // do something with optWidth

        Optional<Integer> optHeight = Arrays.stream(new String[] {"tiff:ImageLength", "Image Height"})
                .map(metadata::get)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(v -> v.replace("pixels", ""))
                .map(Integer::parseInt).findFirst();
        // do something with optHeight
    }
```

I have gotten to this point which does not repeat code:

```
    private static void processDimensions(final Metadata metadata) {
        Optional<Integer> optWidth = processDimension(metadata, "tiff:ImageWidth", "Image Width");
        // do something with optWidth

        Optional<Integer> optHeight = processDimension(metadata, "tiff:ImageLength", "Image Height");
        // do something with optHeight
    }

    private static Optional<Integer> processDimension(final Metadata metadata, @NonNull final String... keys) {
        return Arrays.stream(keys).map(metadata::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(v -> v.replace("pixels", ""))
                .map(Integer::parseInt).findFirst();
    }
```

Is it possible to do this same thing without a separate method such as a Function inside *processDimensions()*?  How would that look?

Comment: _How would that look?_: bad. what you have in place is what you should be doing.

Comment: Like already shown in an answer below, you can declare a `Function` instead of a method. While this *technically* solves your problem, it doesn't really pose a factual improvement over your solution, it's simply a different way to do exactly same (Since you create an anonymous class instead of method). I'd personally prefer the `Function` approach, but that's more about opinion than actual improvements, at least in this case.

Comment: A loop over the two inputs would do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes declare it as a `java.util.Function` and reuse it.

```
Function<String[], OptionalInt> funct = keys -> Arrays.stream(keys)
    .map(metadata::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(v -> v.replace("pixels", ""))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .findFirst();
```

Here's how you call it.

```
funct.apply(strArr);
```

In fact, declaring a method gives a much more readable name such as `processDimensions` and you declare parameter types with more descriptive names than a lambda, hence it is much more readable to me. Unless you are well versed with streams, you may find hard time reading this pipeline. Moreover, a method defines a de facto API, but a stream pipeline usually doesn't.

Comment: I figured it was possible but I overlooked the apply() method of a Function.  Many thanks.

Comment: @MarkSholund so you are not OK declaring a method, but OK declaring a Function. funny.

Comment: I didn't say I was not fine declaring a method.  I wanted to know if and how to do the same thing with a Function.

Comment: @MarkSholund ah! now it makes sense, you even corrected the description. good job.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
        private static Optional<Integer> processDimension(final Metadata, dim) {
            return Arrays.stream(new String[] {"tiff:Image" + dim, "Image " + dim})
                    .map(metadata::get)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(v -> v.replace("pixels", ""))
                    .map(Integer::parseInt).findFirst();
        }
```

And call it like so.

```
        int width = processDimension(metadata, "Width").get();
        int height = processDimension(metadata, "Height").get();
```

You may want to use a different method to retrieve the `optional` to provide a default.

Comment: The question was about solving the problem **without** an extra method.

Comment: What do you think a lambda calls?

Comment: The method of a functional interface, but that's not my point. Your solution is almost identical to the workaround that is already written in the original question (And had been declined by the author as "non sufficient"), so it obviously not what they were searching for. I know that we're merely talking about syntactical differences here, but the author seems to be interested in a syntactically different solution (Judging by the accepted answer), and declaring a lambda *technically* solves the question, since it introduces a class instead of a method.

Comment: Actually, the question was about *Creating a Reusable Pipeline* which neither answer solves since pipelines are not reusable.  Both recreate the pipeline each time they are invoked.  Thus my answer is just as good as any.  It also slightly optimizes the call process.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not sure what to call it and "pipeline" seemed the closest description.  I changed the title to better reflect what I was asking.  This answer avoids the duplicate use of "tiff:Image" and "Image" which was not what I was looking for however I did not reject this answer as "non sufficient"